# Jquery scroll not working on IE

Tags: jquery, parallax

I found a demo about parallax scroll. But this one just work on Chrome or Firefox. On Internet Explorer, it seems not work.
    [Demo][1]

Please help me, thanks and sorry about my english!

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/hudsonmarinho/pen/FHGeK
```

Comment: With _does not seems to work_ you mean what exactly?

Comment: In IE, it doesn't scroll the content